# Know if a Service is linked to an Activity

Tags: android

I have 3 ways to have my Android Service running :

1. by opening my Activity (use AlarmManager and PendingIntent to raise the Service periodically)
2. by the system, through BOOT_COMPLETED event being received by a BroadcastReceiver that is declared in the Manifest
3. by the system, if the user kills the application and the Activity that opened the Service, through the START_STICKY flag (the Service is *restarted* with no Activity)

I want to know, *from the Service*, if an Activity is the source of this Service being spawned.

PS: the Service is not bound, since it is spawned from AlarmManager.

Thanks !

Comment: Can't you just send a message to the Service from the Activity when it is in foreground?

Comment: Couldn't you just add a boolean flag or something like that to the `Intent` you use to start the `Service`?